# Is it possible to extend VS code? through plugins or Addons

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to extend VS code? through plugins or Addons?
If so, where can I find resources on how to implement VS code addons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on an extension story: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/9181439-plugins. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no addons or plugins supported. 
But it's already possible to create own plugins. I've made really short description about it here: [Create Custom Language in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687783/create-custom-language-in-visual-studio-code/31023009#31023009)