# Is there a VSCode equivalent to Notepad++'s user defined language configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

I really enjoyed defining syntax highlighting rules in Notepad++ for the various build logs and artifacts I've worked on in the past to make certain text markers pop out. I was wondering if VSCode has any capabilities to do likewise.

For reference to the unfamiliar here's the Notepad++ documentation and a live demonstration:

> https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/
>
> [How to Create Custom Language Definitions in Notepad++](https://youtu.be/_my8gzPN5DU)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is support for something in this direction. The terminology is slightly different though and there may not be a GUI interface like Notedpad++

> Declarative Language Feature
>   [Syntax Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide): VS Code uses **TextMate grammar** for syntax highlighting. This guide will walk you through writing a simple TextMate grammar and converting it into a VS Code extension.

[Create Custom Language in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687783/create-custom-language-in-visual-studio-code)

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview#declarative-language-features

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide