# Port vscode (visual studio code) language server to Visual Studio extension

Tags: ansible, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, language-server-protocol

I want to add ansible DSL (based on yaml) support for Visual Studio 2022 (with extension), I found a language server for ansible DSL in [visual studio code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-language-server), and I want to port this language server into [my extension](https://github.com/soroshsabz/visualstudio-ansible/issues/4) for Visual Studio 2022.

**Can anybody point to any references or even examples of existing porting?**

I think porting with minimal changing is very useful, because we can update language server based on original language server with every changes.

I request sample in https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/issues/279#issue-1589674661

Comment: I found basic Q&A about writing language extension adding to vscode, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30687783/1539100 , but I think it is irrelevant, from my question

Comment: You might first create a completely new extension following this guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2022 and its official sample, and then cut/paste the useful code to your original extension project.

Comment: It is not clear for me to how to use language server (from for example ansible language server) into extension.

Comment: ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2022#main-interface---ilanguageclient You initialize a `ILanguageClient` to point to the LSP server executable. Exactly the same thing like in VS Code.