# How to add new language support in Microsoft VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to add new language support in Microsoft VS Code?
There is a way to add link file extention -> language, but how to add new language?

We develop tools to OpenQASM and need to add file association and language itself to VS Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Custom Language in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687783/create-custom-language-in-visual-studio-code)